# open html file on new window with Python CGI

Tags: python, html, python-3.4

I want to open html file on new window, when push button.

But I can't do. Please advise.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="./cgi-bin/openNewWindow.py" method="POST">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

openNewWindow.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: UTF-8

print("Content-type: text/html")
print("""
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>new window</title>
</head><body>
<h1>new window</h1>
</body></html>
""")
```

cgiserver.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: UTF-8

import http.server

http.server.test(HandlerClass=http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
```

Comment: @traceur yes. I use Python 3.4.0 on windows.